# SSIS Insert records based on field values from CSV and SQL Server data sources

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, merge, lookup

I wonder if the following scenario is possible to be done through SSIS. 

I would like to insert records to SQL Server based on the value in 2 data sources: 1 is CSV file, and 1 SQL Server. For example, 2 data sources, one with the column named Customer ID, another one is from SQL Server with the columns named Task ID and Task Name. I want to insert records to SQL Server with columns named Customer Task ID, Customer ID, Task ID, and Task Name. 

I have tried in several ways without any luck by capturing the Customer ID such as C5000 from Source 1 (CSV file), and then mergeing with the columns of Task ID and Task Name from Source 2 (SQL Server), next inserting the merged records to the destination (SQL Server), and then repeatedly executing the same task to insert records until the last Customer record. I summarized the source and destination samples below. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!

**Source 1 (CSV File)--**

Row 1 contains Customer ID column: C5000

Row 2 contains Customer ID column: C5001

**Source 2 (A table named Task on SQL Server)--** 

Row 1 contains Task ID column: T2000 and Task Name column: Planning

Row 2 contains Task ID column: T2001 and Task Name column: Review

**Destination (A table named Customer Task on SQL Server)--**

Row 1 contains Customer Task ID column: CT0001, Customer ID column: C5000, Task ID column: T2000, Task Name column: Planning

Row 2 contains Customer Task ID column: CT0002, Customer ID column: C5000, Task ID column: T2001, Task Name column: Review

Row 3 contains Customer Task ID column: CT0003, Customer ID column: C5001, Task ID column: T2000, Task Name column: Planning

Row 4 contains Customer Task ID column: CT0004, Customer ID column: C5001, Task ID column: T2001, Task Name column: Review

Answer (score 0):

Use `Cross Join` to do this

```
INSERT INTO Customer_Task
            (Customer_Task_ID,
             Customer_ID,
             Task_ID,
             Task_name)
SELECT 'CT' + RIGHT('000')
       + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Row_number() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))),
       Customer_ID,
       Task_ID,
       Task_name
FROM   Customer
       CROSS JOIN Task
```